# Focus on textbox based on URL

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have two forms on one page and want to have the input boxes focused based on the URL.

So for example: domain.com/Default.aspx#login and domain.com/Default.aspx#register

and the javascript I have this:

```
        if (window.location.href = '?action=login')
        {
            window.document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').focus();
        }
        else if (window.location.href = '?action=register')
        {
            window.document.getElementById('<%=txtRegEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
        }
```

**EDITED**

Comment: are you doing this as a response from some kinda validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf('?action=login', 0) > -1) {
    window.document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').focus();
} else if (url.indexOf('?action=register', 0) > -1) {
    window.document.getElementById('<%=txtRegEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
}
```

Comment: Now we're confusing concepts; if he's doing it with a query string, he should read that query on the server side and only produce one of these two statements. If he uses the hash/anchor/# in the URL he should have a JavaScript `if-else`

Comment: the first part works but the elseif doesn't the IDS are defo correct :/

Comment: @Richard You're right, this seems like it should be handled on the server. Cameron didn't specify at first that he was using ASP.

Comment: doesnt work with my code either seems to hate the the second form :/

Comment: @Richard he can do it both ways. He can parse the URL in the JavaScript and make the decision or parse it with ASP (I guess that's what he uses) and write the appropriate JavaScript. My solution is with JavaScript as he asked for such, but I agree he should go for server-side parsing and then output the ID with focus() at the end.

Comment: actually i did specify at first i was using ASP :) fixed the problem anyways turns out the JS needed to be at the bottom of the page. Thanks

Comment: @Cameron <body onload="done()"> and then wrap all your javascript inside function done() {} so you are sure it is started on load.

Comment: @Ivo Sabev - You're right, he _can_ do it both ways, but I think one shouldn't interpret the query string with JS. His initial question was about using the anchor `#login` and `#register` which is much more consistent with a JS solution; but once he moved over to query string, the whole thing kind of lost cohesiveness! :)

Answer (score 1):

You either want to do this only on the server side using query strings...

(I code too much PHP and my Asp.NET is a little rust so this code snippet might have syntax/langauage errors...)

```
<%
    if("login".Equals(Request.QueryString["action"])) {
        %>
        window.document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').focus();
        <%
    }
    else if("register".Equals(Request.QueryString["action"])) {
        %>
        window.document.getElementById('<%=txtRegEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
        <%
    }
%>
```

Or on the client side with javascript and the anchor `#login`

```
var url = window.location.hash;

if (url == "#action") {
    window.document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>').focus();
} else if (url == "#register") {
    window.document.getElementById('<%=txtRegEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url using `window.location.href`, and do a simple string test on it to see which focus to set. Either form of the url (anchor or querystring) should work.

Edit: You can learn more about the `window.location` object [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location).

Edit 2: Given your added code example, it looks like you're using ASP or ASP.Net. If so, you should probably handle this on the server side, having just one `focus()` call and setting the element id (the "`<%= %>`" part) on the server side based on the `Request.Querystring` object.

Comment: Might be better to use `window.location.hash`.

Comment: location.href is just a simple string that gives the current url. You can also use some other properties of the location object if you want to be more specific, as Richard noted; I added a link with more explanation.

Comment: Almost, you would want to use location.search instead of location.href in that case, because href gets you the full url, whereas search just gives you the querystring piece. Oh, and be sure to use "==" instead of "=", otherwise you'll be *changing* the url instead of comparing to it!